# 24-0-24 Rectified DC Circuit

Tags: ac

I've been attempting to build my first lab power supply, I have my components, and have studied many circuit diagrams. I thought my knowledge was good enough, however I'm now at an impass. I have a 24-0-24 30w transformer. Now I get the following readings when measuring from the shown points;

[image: 1]

When I measure between the two 24v outputs I get  the following;

[image: 2]

FYI my end goal is to produce a 0-35V DC power supply unit using lM317T.

Now I want to use a four diode (namley 1n4001) bridge to rectify the output to DC, something like this;

[image: 3]

Ok thanks for the super quick reply, so the revised circuit design is the following:

[image: 4]

Now here I get the following readings which are confusing to me;

[image: 7]

[image: 8]

Here is the overall circuit

[image]

I'm sorry if I come across as stupid but, I just don't quite seam to understand the readings I am getting.

Comment: Everything looks in order so far. The transformer is unloaded so the voltage will be a bit high. At the rated current it will probably be close to 24 V AC. I'd like to see a fuse in the mains supply though.

Comment: I am sorry I do not know how to comment properly, I keep editing the main post.

Comment: After you make your 1st brute force unregulated supply at high current you will realize the 1N400x diodes and the series regulators will overheat and you only get 75% best case of TFMR rated power. So then you will want to make  a better supply , a SMPS with a good line filter on input and output. but smaller magnetics and caps but  ultralow ESR.  WHy make it and why not simulate it in real-time?

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/yb2nv2w6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a 24-0-24 30w transformer. Now I get the following readings when measuring from the shown points.

[image]

*Figure 1. One schematic will do for all your measurements once it's labelled.*

As mentioned in my comment, the 24 V output voltage will depend on the input voltage and the output load. A higher input voltage will result in a higher output voltage. An bigger load (lower resistance) will cause the output voltage to sag somewhat. It should be 24 V at the rated load. So, since your measurements are taken with the circuit unloaded V<sub>1-2</sub> and V<sub>2-3</sub> look fine.

V<sub>1-3</sub> also looks fine as it should be the sum of V<sub>1-2</sub> and V<sub>2-3</sub>.

Now we come to the rectifier. The peak of a sinewave (which is what your AC is) will be \$ \sqrt 2 V_{RMS} \$. Your meter is giving you the RMS value so the peak should be about 38 V. The capacitors will hold the voltage at that level while the mains voltage dips. So you should expect V<sub>4-5</sub> to read +38 V (black probe at 5) and V<sub>6-5</sub> to read about -38 V (again with the black probe at 5). V<sub>4-6</sub> should read double that.

The arrangement you have chosen is standard when a dual or split-rail power supply is required. I suspect that you only require a single rail supply and if so you can omit D1, D4, C2 and C4. Your DC output will appear on 4 (+) and 5 (-).

The LM317 is a forty year-old design and while it still works as well as ever you need to be aware of the power limitations. It is, in effect, acting as a variable resistor to burn up some of the voltage between your rectifier and your load. The voltage drop across the LM317 times the current through it is the power that the poor little chip will have to dissipate. P = VI. Do your calculations.

Most modern designs are using switched-mode power-supplies (SMPS) but these are difficult for beginners due to the mains voltages present. An alternative is to use a buck converter after your smoothing capacitors. These switch at high frequency and waste much less power and, therefore, heat.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to study your comment, you clearly know what your talking about (brain is currently on floor*). Ok I'm getting it now. I'm going to breadboard and I'll be back. Thank you

Comment: Right so I have just rewired my circuit and I now have 48.6V DC through my diode bridge. I was have trouble before receiving AC voltage through my circuit, clearly the wiring was incorrect as some of my capicitors exploded (it was a fun expirence) however following your guidence I have been able to get to the next part of my challenge. I will keep you updated. P.S how do I insert new images in the comments>?

Comment: Ok now I am confused again, I now have 106V AC and  48.6V DC measured between 4 and 6. I understand the DC but not the AC value I'm getting (currently mesauring the vaules without the capicators in place)

Comment: Comments don't take images. They belong in your question. On 4 and 6 you should be using the DC volts range. Why have you got terminal 6 now if you're now using a single ended supply?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm just trying to piece the circuit together step by step and understand the readings I'm getting. I have some knowledge of eletronics,  however I start to get lost when the square root of a voltage is mentioned (suggestions to improve welcomed).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build a 0-35V DC power supply your circuit is not the most efficient way to do it. What you have shown would be good to create a +/-35V supply.
Here is an example circuit (not the same transformer voltages) where you would use a center tapped transformer to create a supply:

[image]

If what you want is a single 0-35V supply, then you'd build as shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUoGYO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here you only need a single filter capacitor and two diodes.
You of course need to select the diodes and filter cap to suit your application.
27V RMS unloaded is going to be tight to create a 35VDC supply since 27 * 1.414 = 38Vdc. Depending on your load and the drop in the transformer voltage I would suggest you'd be struggling to get 30VDC under the best of circumstances. The 1N4001 has about a 1V Vf, and you have to allow for ripple and the minimum voltage for the regulator ([LM317](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaLpO.jpg)) input/output differential of 3V.

You could use two Schottky diodes to lower the Vf, but if the transformer under even a light load drops close to 24V RMS, then you will likely see an upper DC voltage of 30VDC, so again allowing for ripple and the regulator you will be limited to about 24-26VDC regulated.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, If I could figure out how to post images I would post the rest of the curcuit

Comment: Ok I have inserted the full curcuit diagram in the orginal post